# Why I can`t trigger success callback in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have following code:

```
App.Views.UseCategory = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: HandlebarsTemplates['uses/useCategory'],

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addCategory');
    this.render();
  },

  events: {
    'submit #addCategoryForm': 'addCategory'
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).append(this.template(this.options));
    return this;
  },

  addCategory: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var useCategoryId = $('select[id=use_category_id]').val();

    this.model.set('category_id', parseInt(useCategoryId,10));
    this.model.save({ success: console.log('success') });
  }
});
```

Code above works and trigger success callback, so I receive in console "success".

But why when I change that addCategory function to:

```
  addCategory: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var useCategoryId = $('select[id=use_category_id]').val();

    this.model.set('category_id', parseInt(useCategoryId,10));
    console.log('save?');
    this.model.save({ success: this.addedCategory, error: function() { console.error(arguments) } });
  },

  addedCategory: function() {
    console.log('success');
  }
```

success callback is not triggered anymore, why?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: You can remove this line: `_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addCategory');`, also do not call `$.append()` inside `render()` but `$.html()` in case your render your view multiple times.

Comment: Hmm, I have to use append because this view is rendered from another view: https://gist.github.com/d7488043e654e9f313de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
this.model.save({ success: console.log('success') });
```

You already call your console log. What you should do is (not the same):

```
this.model.save({ success: function() {
    console.log('success')
} });
```

Do you understand the difference or do you need clarifications?

In fact i suspect your `success` callback is never called.

**EDIT:**

`model.save(data, opts)` takes two arguments. You should do:

```
this.model.save({}, { success: function() {
    console.log('success')
} });
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So how should I write this to be correct? => https://gist.github.com/6f056457208d99fcbfd1

Comment: It seems correct, can you try: `this.model.save({ success: this.addedCategory, error: function() { console.error(arguments) } });` it should help you to debug it. Also check that `model.save()` is really called by adding a `console.log` just before.

Comment: Hmm, I used your suggestion but now I dont see 'success' or any error. How should I interpreted that?

Comment: model.save() do not seems to be called try adding a console.log just before it. Also check the "Network" tab in firebug and see if there's your ajax request.

Comment: Ajax response status is 200. Also I see save? in console. added console.log like above.

Comment: Ok, i spotted the problem, save take two arguments, see http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save. You should do `this.model.save({}, { success: this.addedCategory })`

Comment: Thx, Error start shows. Last thing: How to read that console error output.

Comment: `console.error` show you a stack trace, nice to help debugging. You can also try: `{ success: ..., error: function(model, error) { console.log(error); } }`